# fetching JSON data by spark-SQL

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When i try to fetch the nested JSON data by using Spark-SQL query:

```
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("sql").setMaster("local"));
SQLContext  sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("path_to_s3_bucket").cache();
df.registerTempTable("table_name");
DataFrame d=sqlContext.sql("Select address.state as state from table_name");
```

I am getting th following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from address
```

My Json data is like:-

```
"address":{"city":"xyz","state":"abc","country":"pqr"}
```

Please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: how did you read the json into the table? Please provide the code of what you did...

Comment: I have saved the edits.

Comment: try doing df.show() and df.printSchema on the dataframe before registring

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid. It should be:
                                                                                       {"address":{"city":"xyz","state":"abc","country":"pqr"}}